# How to write in file?

Tags: tcl, proc

I would like to write in file like this:

```
set fh [open $tmpFileName w]
puts $fh "set a [create_object]"
puts $fh "$a proc1_inside_a"
puts $fh "$a proc2_inside_a"
close $fh
```

But its get the error message, because `a` variable will be created when `tmpFileName` file will be executed. So I get the error like this:

```
can't read "a": no such variable
```

Can you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: what do you want to write into the file? the value of `create_object` or `[create_object]`?

Comment: [Johannes Kuhn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn) [create object]

Comment: In this case, you should escape the `[`. Either by enclosing the entire string with `{}` or with a ``\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a different quoting mechanism. Double quotes allow command and variable substitution. Braces will keep their contents verbatim (inhibit substutition)

```
set fh [open $tmpFileName w]
puts $fh {set a [create_object]}
puts $fh {$a proc1_inside_a}
puts $fh {$a proc2_inside_a}
close $fh
```

Documentation is available:

- Tcl's very few [syntax rules](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) -- compare rule 4 vs rule 6
- the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) -- lessons 5 and 6 apply

Comment: +1 but I might write that as a single multi-line literal myself…